# Method for sorting VMWareVMs by annotation fields

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, sort

**Background:**
One of the policies of  our vCenter cluster is for (almost) every VM to have an "expiration date". This is a custom field in the annotations panel that is mainly a reminder to contact the owner of the VM and verify the system is still relevant.

**My question**: What is the best way to sort through a group of VMs by a particular annotation field? Are there any tools that VMWare provides to view VMs by their annotation summaries? Or is there a better way to accomplish the goal of tracking VM lifespans altogether?

Comment: That's got perl sdk written all over it I'm afraid, nothing in the standard tool set sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

powercli handles this pretty easily. http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/

`get-vm | get-annotation -customattribute $my_annotation | sort -property value`

or if you want to export to csv and work with the data there:

`get-vm | get-annotation -customattribute $my_annotation | select annotatedentity, name, value | export-csv -notypeinformation`